# In WebApi, where should I save data between calls to my ActionFilter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which does some stuff both before and after the target action.  I would like to save the state of the `Executing` call for use in the `Executed` call - but where should I save this data?

I would expect something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    actionContext.SavedState = Precomputation();
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var pre = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.SavedState;
    Postcomputation(pre);
}
```

but `SavedState` doesn't actually exist, of course.  What should I use instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add items to `actionContext.Request.Properties` as required.