# How to modify the form-data contents of an HttpRequestMessage in the ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to **modify** the form-data content of an `HttpRequestMessage` in a filter or `HttpMessageHandler`.

I want to read a value from the querystring and dependent on certain logic I want to update the contents of the form-data passed in the `HttpRequestMessage` before it hits the action method on the controller, that way I can still rely on the built in model binding and check the `ModelState.IsValid()` method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the request content can be modified as it is a "read once" stream. What sort of changes are you making to the content?

Comment: An API key will be passed in the query string. From this key I can produce a user id (I want the caller to know their API key but not their actual user id). I want to put that user id in the form data which becomes part of the object that will be model bound to the action method parameter. In my experiments I noticed that the request content is a "read once" stream so its looking unlikely that I can go this route. Can you think of another way to approach this, preferably without me having to change all my action methods.

Comment: You could put the data in the request properties (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239216/in-webapi-where-should-i-save-data-between-calls-to-my-actionfilter/12239690#12239690). What if you didn't make the user information part of the model at all?

Comment: The request properties seems like a possibility. I'll give it a try tomorrow, thanks for the tip.

Comment: In the end I had to take out the UserId from the models. In the authenticate filter I used the ApiKey to retrieve the real UserId and stored it in a property of the controller. In each of my action methods I accessed the controller's UserId property. I was hoping not to have had to that line of code in each of my action methods but there doesn't appear to be a good alternative. Anyway, thanks for your help.